# Issue with images in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla, joomla-template

I'm trying to update a website for a friend on the Joomla CMS. A developer was setting it up and then bolted, now I'm trying to finish updating the site for him.

I am new to Joomla and don't have any developer experience with it (I use Wordpress). Currently the issue I am having is that when I insert an image using the editor, Joomla resizes the image into a thumbnail format, and then places it in the top left corner of the web page (rather than in the post where it is suppose to be).

I've tried using relative url for the image, and absolute url's to link directly to the image with no luck.

The thing I don't understand though is that I have a Paypal image that displays fine, but the image that's hosted in joomla won't show up correctly.

Here's the sample code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://worldofchaisson.com/images/chaisson.png" alt="Rise of Chaisson on DVD" /></td>
<td>

    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="4EPQ2WR7UCD6L">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Pretty self explanitory. 2 column table. 1st column has the image of the DVD that is being sold, and the second has the paypal purchase code/url. In any other environment it would work perfectly.

Here's the website so you can see what I'm talking about: http://www.worldofchaisson.com/

Any help would be great. Please keep in mind though that I am not familiar with the development environment in Joomla, so somewhat detailed explanations will be helpful. Thanks!

Has anyone else had an issue like this?

Comment: Your site link does not show your image issue. There is no image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ian,

Joomla does  not natively resize images. So your developer must have installed a plugin that is doing this. You may wish to check to see which extensions are installed.

Or see what editor you are using as it may have a setting for resizing images. By default Joomla has the editor off. But TinyMCE is available to users so you can check the settings for that as well. The most powerful editor for Joomla however is: http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/ which allows for a great deal of formatting control though it does cost money.

Cheers,
Chris